# $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x\cdot \sin^2{x}}{x-1}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Calculate:
$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x\cdot \sin^2{x}}{x-1}$$

I don't how to use hopital rule
But i tried to take $X=x-1$ so when $x \to 1$ we get $X \to 0$ but i can't find any result

Comment: @REr i don't really understand what do you mean

Comment: The limit from the left goes toward $-\infty$ while the limit from the right goes toward $\infty$.

Comment: The limit is $\pm\infty$ since the numerator is non-zero at the limit point...

Comment: You can't use l'Hôpital, because the numerator hasn't limit $0$, whereas the denominator has.

Answer (score 4):

> $$\lim_{x \to 1^{+}}\frac{x\cdot \sin^2{x}}{x-1}$$

$$=\lim_{x \to 1^{+}}x\sin^2x\lim_{x \to 1^{+}}\frac{1}{x-1}$$

$$=\sin^2(1)\lim_{x \to 1^{+}}\frac{1}{\underbrace{x-1}_{\to +0}}=\boxed{\infty}$$

---

> $$\lim_{x \to 1^{-}}\frac{x\cdot \sin^2{x}}{x-1}$$

$$=\lim_{x \to 1^{-}}x\sin^2x\lim_{x \to 1^{+}}\frac{1}{x-1}$$

$$=\sin^2(1)\lim_{x \to 1^{-}}\frac{1}{\underbrace{x-1}_{\to -0}}=\boxed{-\infty}$$

$\Longrightarrow\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x\cdot \sin^2{x}}{x-1}$ doet not exist

Comment: $x \to 1$ not just $x \to 1^{+}$

Comment: The OP changed it, I will edit to put more

Answer (score 0):

You could have continued with the change of variable $$\frac{x\cdot \sin^2{x}}{x-1}=\frac{(X+1) \sin ^2(X+1)}{X}=\sin ^2(X+1)+\frac{\sin ^2(X+1)}{X}$$ Now, look at what happens when $X\to 0$.